# Time complexity for a for loop with a multi-variable condition statement

Tags: time, time-complexity

A. What is the complexity (big-O) of the following code fragment?

```
for (i = 0; (i < n) || (i < m); i++) {
sequence of statements
}
```

The best i could come up with is the following..
if n is less then m O(n)
else O(m)
I have no clue how to write big-o in the case where there are two variables.

I know this is a very corner case and basic time complexity question so i do not mind removing it after I get some clarification.

Comment: Assuming the "sequence of statements" does not have any impact, I guess your answer is correct.

Comment: Okay, thank you for the quick response. Yes the  "sequence of statements" portion is in the actual question so i think its safe to assume it has no impact.The question itself is very vague so i believe the emphasis is just on the loop condition. Thanks again, i appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

The time complexity is `O( max(m,n) )` assuming that the body of the loop is `O(1)`.

You say in the question that it would be `O(n)` if `n < m` -- that would be the case if the condition on the for loop used an *and* clause not an *or* clause. The way it is written the loop will iterate as long as `i` is less than the bigger of `m` and `n`, e.g. if `m` is a million and `n` is 0, it is going to iterate a million times. The time complexity scales with the maximum of the two variables.